# azure adal unable to upload files in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, ionic3, office365, azure-active-directory

I am building an Ionic 3 app which will call REST apis of Sharepoint.

I am using [ms-adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) for my ionic 3 project to authenticate to sharepoint and I am using SP-PnP library in my project to do REST requests, I am able to login to sharepoint and do CRUD operations with lists. But, when i try to upload a file in sharepoint document library i am getting 403 (Access denied. You do not have permissions to perform this action). I also checked permissions and my app has delegated permission to read/write items in all site collection.
Do i need any special permissions for uploading files?

[Permissions given in Azure Active Directory App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UocSH.png)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the logged-in user has permissions to upload documents to that particular library? In other words, if as that user you navigate (using a browser) to that SharePoint library, can you upload a document there? Just trying to understand if this is an effective permission issue https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference